# Error on cross join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have below code but, getting error message

```
(select count(*) as countT from dbo.P1 )  a
cross join (select count(*) as cN from dbo.[D2] ) b
cross join  (select count(*) as cM from dbo.m1)  c
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'b'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'c'.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: you are missing the first `SELECT *`: `SELECT * FROM (....your current code here)`

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT col_list from` in your query. Try this way

```
Select countT,cN,cM From 
(select count(*) as countT from dbo.P1 )  a
cross join (select count(*) as cN from dbo.[D2] ) b
cross join  (select count(*) as cM from dbo.m1)  c
```

Since all the sub-queries going to return one row as result you can do this as well.

```
Select (select count(*) as countT from dbo.P1 )  countT
       , (select count(*) as cN from dbo.[D2] ) cN
       , (select count(*) as cM from dbo.m1)  cM
```